# wget decides not to load because of black list

Tags: download, wget, web-crawler

I'm trying to make a full copy of a web site; e.g.,

```
http://vfilesarchive.bgmod.com/files/
```

I'm running

```
wget -r -level=inf -R "index.html*" --debug http://vfilesarchive.bgmod.com/files/
```

and getting, for example

```
Deciding whether to enqueue "http://vfilesarchive.bgmod.com/files/Half-Life%D0%92%D0%86/".
Already on the black list.
Decided NOT to load it.
```

What is happening? 
What does `wget` mean by "black list",
why is it downloading only parts of what is there,
and what should I do to get the entire web site?

The version of wget is

```
GNU Wget 1.20 built on mingw32
```

(running on Windows 10 x64).

P.S. I think I've managed to solve this with

```
wget -m --restrict-file-names=nocontrol --no-iri -R "index.html*" <target url>
```

even though the filenames are slightly crippled
due to special chars in URLs. 
Is there a better solution?

Comment: Welcome to Super User, and kudos for solving the problem.  The site's Q&A format relies on questions being just questions, and solutions being in answer posts.  With your clarification, the question has been taken off hold.  Please move you solution to an answer (you can answer your own question).  Two days after posting the question, you can accept your own answer by clicking the checkmark there.  That will indicate that the problem has been solved.

Comment: @fixer1234: When you posted the above comment,  I was in the process of editing the question into a broader “why?” / “what does it mean?” query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've managed to solve this with

```
wget -m --restrict-file-names=nocontrol --no-iri -R "index.html*" <target url>
```

even though the filenames are slightly crippled due to special chars in URLs.