# What exactly does 'black list" mean in wget?

Tags: wget, web-crawler

I'm running the following command

```
wget -d -e robots=off --recursive -l 10 -w 6.8 -t 3 -nc --random-wait -T 10 -R "*.js, *.css, *.jsp, *.mp3, *.mp4, *.swf, *.apk, *.pdf, *.css, *.doc, *.docx, *.xls, *.xlsx, *.jpg, *.jpeg, *.gif, *.JPG, *.JPEG, *.png, *.PNG" --server-response http://www.wuli.ac.cn/CN/volumn/home.shtml --user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:69.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/69.0" -a wget_log &
```

Which displays the options as below,

```
Setting --recursive (recursive) to 1
Setting --level (reclevel) to 10
Setting --wait (wait) to 6.8
Setting --tries (tries) to 3
Setting --no (noclobber) to 1
Setting --random-wait (randomwait) to 1
Setting --timeout (timeout) to 10
Setting --reject (reject) to *.js, *.css, *.jsp, *.mp3, *.mp4, *.swf, *.apk, *.pdf, *.css, *.doc, *.docx, *.xls, *.xlsx, *.jpg, *.jpeg, *.gif, *.JPG, *.JPEG, *.png, *.PNG
Setting --server-response (serverresponse) to 1
Setting --user-agent (useragent) to Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:69.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/69.0
Setting --append-output (logfile) to wget_log
```

But then I get a lot of debug output like the following:

```
Deciding whether to enqueue "http://www.wuli.ac.cn/CN/column/column3290.shtml".
Already on the black list.
Decided NOT to load it.
Deciding whether to enqueue "http://www.wuli.ac.cn/CN/column/column3290.shtml".
Already on the black list.
Decided NOT to load it.
Deciding whether to enqueue "http://www.wuli.ac.cn/CN/column/column3291.shtml".
Already on the black list.
Decided NOT to load it.
Deciding whether to enqueue "http://www.wuli.ac.cn/CN/column/column3293.shtml".
Already on the black list.
Decided NOT to load it.
Deciding whether to enqueue "http://www.wuli.ac.cn/CN/column/column3294.shtml".
Already on the black list.
Decided NOT to load it.
Deciding whether to enqueue "http://www.wuli.ac.cn/CN/column/column3290.shtml".
Already on the black list.
Decided NOT to load it.
```

I don't quite see where I'm "black listing" these.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [wget decides not to load because of black list](https://superuser.com/questions/1398858/wget-decides-not-to-load-because-of-black-list)

Comment: @harrymc I have seen that post, but id doesn't solve my problem, neither does itanswer my question.

Comment: Please explain why.

Comment: Have you read the answer to the question? It just says "this and this worked for me". But that doesn't answer the question: What is the "black list" and how exactly does wget decide what belongs there. As for the practical problem, applying any of those flags in that answer doesn't solve the problem, "Already on black list" still appears in my log.

Comment: In that case I retract my vote.

Answer (score 1):

You are not black-listing any webpage, it is `wget` that does it.

Basically, any webpage being downloaded by `wget` is entered into a "black list"
that is supposed to avoid downloading the same page twice.

The problem occurs on webpages that use double redirection, bouncing the
request to some "security check" and back.
Wget does not expect to be redirected a second time to the same page,
finds it in the black list, thus skipping the download of that page.

This problem was first mentioned in 2012 in GNU WGET
[bug #37986: Redirection to the same url prevents recursion](http://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?37986)
and a fix was implemented, which apparently did not reach your Linux distribution or
was lost after so many years.

The only solution, besides finding another downloader or wget version,
is mentioned in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/347659/17660).

> However, if you are willing to
>   recompile wget manually, the fix to your issue can be trivial: just add these 2
>   lines in `src/recur.c`.
>
> ```
>             status = retrieve_url (url_parsed, url, &file, &redirected, referer,
>                                    &dt, false, i, true);
> +
> +         if (redirected)
> +                 hash_table_remove (blacklist, url);
>
>             if (html_allowed && file && status == RETROK
>                 && (dt & RETROKF) && (dt & TEXTHTML))
> ```
>
> That will remove the current page from the blacklist every time you
>   are redirected, thus fixing your issue.
>
> Be warned that it could possibly trigger infinite loops in some cases,
>   so it's not a submission-ready patch.